# How can I add submenus for pop up menu programatically?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

In  my plugin, I  have a pop up menu with menu item 'X' and I want to add submenu to this menu item

and the number and labels  of menu items in the submenu and their action will change.

I think I can';t do this from plugin.xml, so how to do this programatically?

Comment: Where is the menu, registered as a part menu from a view?

Comment: Yes, It's registered on a view and it's shown upon a right click in this view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your **plugin.xml**, under **org.eclipse.ui.menus**, add a **menuContribution** that refers to the id of your "root" menu, i.e. the menu that you want to have your submenus attached to (in this case, **menu:myDynamicMenuRoot**):

```
<menuContribution
    allPopups="true"
    class="com.myCode.menus.MyDynamicMenuContributions"
    locationURI="menu:myDynamicMenuRoot">
</menuContribution>
```

Note that **allPopups="true"** ensures that your submenus will be added to any menu with the id **myDynamicMenuRoot** that you add anywhere in your application.

Finally, create a class extending ExtensionContributionFactory, whose job it will be to create your dynamic submenu items.  Here I add items based on commands I have defined in my **plugin.xml**:

```
public class MyDynamicMenuContributions extends ExtensionContributionFactory {
    private static final ImageDescriptor GREEN_STAR = Plugin.getImageDescriptor("icons/green_star.png");

    @Override
    public void createContributionItems(IServiceLocator serviceLocator, IContributionRoot additions) {
        // build a couple of command-based contribution parameters
        CommandContributionItemParameter pAA = new CommandContributionItemParameter(
            serviceLocator,
            "Submenu_CommandAA",
            "my.package.command.myCommandAA",
            SWT.PUSH);
        pAA.icon = GREEN_STAR;
        pAA.label = "Command AA";

        CommandContributionItemParameter pBB = new CommandContributionItemParameter(
            serviceLocator,
            "Submenu_CommandBB",
            "my.package.command.myCommandBB",
            SWT.PUSH);
        pBB.icon = GREEN_STAR;
        pBB.label = "Command BB";

        // create actual contribution items and add them to the given additions reference
        CommandContributionItem itemAA = new CommandContributionItem(pAA);
        itemAA.setVisible(true);
        additions.addContributionItem(itemAA, null);

        CommandContributionItem itemBB = new CommandContributionItem(pBB);
        itemBB.setVisible(true);
        additions.addContributionItem(itemBB, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need a popup: scheme to work with popup menus (allPopups is only considered after the system determines that it is a popup menu).

Comment: Your menu contribution here is programmatic, but will only be applied once on creation, as opposed to menu Show events.  Instead of a class try the `dynamic` element in the `menuContribution`, and implement `org.eclipse.ui.actions.CompoundContributionItem`

Comment: @PaulWebster Your first point kind of goes without saying, doesn't it; you can't make a popup menu without a popup: scheme.  Your second point is an excellent one; I pulled this code from a project of mine that builds a menu dynamically _at app startup_, but those menus don't change after that point.  From the sounds of the question, `dynamic` etc. is definitely the way to go for @becks.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll consider all your comments :)